# Sort the color of records based on a list of colors

Tags: javascript

I have a list of colors, I need to sort the color of the records based on this list.

I need that after selecting the last color from the list, the loop returns to the first color.

**Current result:**

[image: Current result]

**Expected result:**

[image: Expected result]

[See in Sandbox!](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamics-colors-sort-fsl7b?file=/src/App.js)

Thanks for your help

**Colors list**

```
const colorsList = [
  "#57D9A3",
  "#00C7E6",
  "#4C9AFF",
  "#998DD9",
  "#FF8F73",
  "#FFC400",
  "#7092BE",
  "#79F2C0",
  "#79E2F2",
  "#b3D4FF",
  "#c0b6F2",
  "#FFBDAD",
  "#FFE380",
  "#B9CADF"
];
```

**Records**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, …, 46]
```

**Current logic**

```
const handleColor = (index) => {
    let color;
    let idx = 0;
    if (index < 14) {
      color = colorsList[index];
    } else {
      //what logic to use?
    }
    return color;
  };
....
<Box className="App">
      <h1>Dynamic Colors sort Javascript</h1>
      <Box display="flex" alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
        <List className={classes.colorContent}>
          {records &&
            records.map((item, index) => (
              <IconButton
                key={index}
                className={classes.colorButton}
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: handleColor(index)
                }}
              >
                <Typography variant="caption">{item}</Typography>
              </IconButton>
            ))}
        </List>
      </Box>
    </Box>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `%` operator, so that It will return the `remainder` repeatedly. So If the remainder is same then the color will also be same.

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

```
const handleColor = (index) => colorsList[index % colorsList.length];
```